# How do I replace a JSON string with its parsed equivalent in place with jq?

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON array with a bunch of objects, all the same keys, but some of the keys contain serialized JSON instead of actual JSON. Something like this.

```js
[
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": "{\"c\":2}"
  },
]
```

and I'd like to replace the contents of all the `b`s with their parsed form.

```js
[
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": { "c": 2 }
  },
]
```

How can I do this, ideally with jq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fromjson`, and update the fields in question using `.[].b |=`.

```bash
.[].b |= fromjson
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/NAgc9RiyBf6)

If you want to decode all JSON-encoded strings, unknowing which ones are, you could `try` using `fromjson`, and in case of a failure resort to the original input `.`. `try` can be abbreviated to `?`:

```bash
.[][] |= (fromjson? // .)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/fIHctyWqpMa)

Both output:

```json
[
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": {
      "c": 2
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: The `|=` bit is what I was struggling to find, thanks! Your second solution doesn't work with jq 1.6 that I was using, as in it nukes the key it's supposed to replace. Upgraded to 1.7 and it works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @Morpheu5 Yes, there was a bug in jq 1.6 when the update operator needed to operate in different context types. You could avoid the bug by creating a unique context, like an array, and then extract from it the right part, e.g. `.[][] |= [fromjson?, .][0]`. But updating to a more recent version is always the better option.